# How is someone accessing my mysql database once per day and, especially, why?

Tags: mysql, security

Every day, around the same time, someone/something accesses a mysql db I administer and inserts a record in all the tables except the "logins" table. The inserts are always the number "1" in all the fields that will accept an integer. How are they doing that? And why?

I've looked at the log files to figure out the IP of my mysterious visitor, then blocked that IP, but it doesn't seem to matter. My tables are all populated with a new record of 1's the next day, same time. I even blocked their whole country, but, the next day, same thing.

These inserts started the day I created the db. And I've never given the password out to anyone. The database services one domain (unGoogle.us). I have numerous other domains and databases, and I've never seen this behavior on any of them except this one.

Does anyone know how they could be doing this? More importantly (for my sanity), *why* anyone would be doing this?

Comment: Did you try changing the root password and all of the other passwords for access, and does it still happen after you change the passwords?

Comment: so you found the IP in the logs and blocked that but the inserts continued?  do you see continuing accesses in your logs? if not, check if ischeduled events got set up to do the inserts?

Comment: @Sablefoste No, I haven't tried that, but it's a good idea and I will do that. He/she/they/it is due back in about 12 hours, so I'll let you know whether it works. Even if it works, though, and stops the visits, I'll be just as perplexed by how they got my password immediately, not to mention why they came by everyday just to insert such an innocuous record. What do they gain?

Comment: perhaps it's code rather than a person. if they put an `INSERT` in your code, they wouldn't need to have access. Why? Good question.

Comment: @ysth I just checked the logs, and see no visits at all from the country I blocked during the hour they always visit--and the country was China, so that's saying something to have no visits from there at all. I do see a half dozen visits from Huawei in Singapore, though. There is also a visit from The Endurance International Group, Inc, which, I believe, was present in previous logfiles (which I wish I'd kept). Its reverse dns is 65-254-225-171.yourhostingaccount.com, Burlington, MA but I think I remember them resolving to South Dakota before. Or it could be an angry googlebot, ungoogle.us :)

Comment: well they were back again this morning right on schedule

Comment: If you changed all of your passwords, then there must be a process doing this, most likely an internal MYSQL process.  I don't know what it could be.  What type of tables are you using? INNODB?

Comment: @Sablefoste Yes, InnoDB tables. But they didn't come by this morning or yesterday morning

Comment: @Mech It's weird. It always comes at 9:23 a.m., which makes me think it's a bot/chron/code thing, but then, like a couple of days ago, it put two records in one table, one in another, and left the rest alone, which seems more humanish to me to mix it up like that. Well, maybe they/it are gone for good. Yet and still, I wonder "Why?"

Comment: sounds like a cron job. what cms are you using?

Comment: @Mech I'm not using a cms. Also, I checked to see whether there was anything tripping on the server... nothing. https://ungoogle.us

Comment: do you use version controls? git?

Comment: @mech No, I don't. I'm the only person who writes the code or builds the site. Simple php, straightforward LAMP set up. I am on a shared server though

Comment: only one who codes doesn't matter for this exact reason. a roll back could save your time in this case.

Comment: "Save my time"? Should we move to chat? The robot is yelling at me.

Comment: Well, they were back at 9:36 this morning. I think I might try creating a new "root" directory in my existing root, then pointing my server there, put all the content except sensitive data in the new root, and calling sensitive data like db login from inside the new root.

Comment: I found this in my logfile: /.well-known/openpgpkey/ungoogle.us/policy That's the url someone entered the site with. The domain name is the "ungoogle.us" part.